# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0 on asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to asp.net core and my first attempt on Web api project

My project.json:

```
  {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Dapper": "1.50.2",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1",
    "MicroOrm.Pocos.SqlGenerator": "1.0.0.3"

  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "net461",
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
```

It shows error on Microsoft Application Insights after I've put in `""Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1"` and imported

```
"imports": [
        "net461",
```

System.IO.FileLoadException
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.TelemetryConfigurationFactory..cctor(

Web.config:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please check you web config and find that reference and its dependant assemblies , this error occur due to conflict either in config and pakage config,

or 

check you dll and go to its property , find the version number , match that version number in config files.

Comment: web.config is very simple, I've updated the question. Have you tried with asp.net core ?

Comment: It could be the version of one of your dependencies like for example Dapper or MicroOrm.Pocos.SqlGenerator. I had a similar problem when using Markdig -> 0.10.4 (It works locally but failing on Azure). I updated it to the latest version 0.10.6 and everything worked fine. It means that the version 0.10.4 was not compatible with .NETCore